# Renaming a typescript file

Tags: typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rename a Typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262244/rename-a-typescript-file)

Hi can anyone point to why I would fix this error in a typescript project in VS 2012

I renamed a typescript file and compiled and expected the autogenerated JS file to change name to the new TS name (the one you see when you expand the arrow) but it doesn't, but rather adds the new JS file at the same level as the TS file. It would be nicer to have the js file under the arrow as the default way.

Alternatively I can delete the TS as described here and redo it but that is no fun

[Rename a Typescript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262244/rename-a-typescript-file)